# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error when trying to rebuild project after generating User Interface tests using Android Test recorder plugin for Android studio (http://droidtestlab.com/).

Every time I have to relaunch Android studio and Emulator to Get rid of this error.

Tried cleaning project then got this error,

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
:clean
:app:clean FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: E:\..\AndroidStudio\..\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong here?
How can I fix this error?

Using Android studio 2.1.1 and Android 6.0, Nexus 5X API 23 emulator